# System Out of memory exception when deserialising a byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, sql-server, memory, byte

I have a table with raw outputs in SQL, I am using SQL Command Reader to loop through a table and deserialise data. The method to deserialise is throwing System.OutOfMemory exception.

I am using .Net 4.5 and SQL Server 2014.

```
using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (rdr.Read())
    {  
       byte[] ioNames = null;

        long ioNamesArraySize = rdr.GetBytes(ApplicationConstants.ord_IONames, 0, null, 0, 0);
        ioNames = new byte[ioNamesArraySize];
        ioNames = (byte[])rdr[ApplicationConstants.ord_IONames];

    // Get the data.
    byte[] outputs = null;
    long outputsArraySize = rdr.GetBytes(ApplicationConstants.ord_RawData, 0, null, 0, 0);
    outputs = new byte[outputsArraySize];
    outputs = (byte[])rdr[ApplicationConstants.ord_RawData];

    // Extract the InstrumentOutputNames and Outputs.
    object[][] data = null;
    data = outputs.DeserializeFromByteArray<object[][]>();
    // The below line throws the exception.                
    var iPms = ioNames.DeserializeFromByteArray<IEnumerable<InstrumentParameter>>();
    iPms = iPms.ToList();
}

/// <summary>
/// Deserializes the specified byte array.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Type to Use</typeparam>
/// <param name="byteArray">The byte array.</param>
/// <returns>T.</returns>
public static T DeserializeFromByteArray<T>(this byte[] byteArray)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
    {
        return (T)new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(ms);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is ioNames? Did you mean to call outputs.DeserializeFromByteArray instead?

Comment: @Polyfun -  Thanks for looking into this. My fault, I have updated the code now.  Feel free to ask questions if any.

Comment: @SuperOil - Thank you, you edits will make the question more readble, I am fairly new to StackOverflow still learning.

Comment: Please make sure I formatted your code properly though. `ionames` seems to be declared inside the `while` loop but used outside.

Comment: @SuperOli Thank you again. It was a copy paste error.

Comment: What is the SQL Server data type of the columns you are trying to read? I am not sure why you need to deserialize these columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fristly thanks to everyone for looking into this. This issue is resolved by simply changing the application build properties.

- Uncheck Prefer 32 bit
- Select 64 bit not any CPU.

This works fine. Hope someone will find this helpful.